# Rsync over ssh in a crontab job will not work

Tags: linux, debian, cron, rsync

I am trying to back up a folder on a web server from a file server. I have tested it manually and it works without me needing to enter a password for the SSH connection. When I put it in the crontab and wait a while however, nothing happens and it's hard to debug the problem when there's no output at all. My crontab looks like this:

```
01 * * * * sftpadmin rsync --delete -avh --progress -e ssh /home/sftpadmin/www/html jobhandler@10.5.5.16:/var/www/
```

EDIT: Probably should have mentioned I am trying to get the script to run every minute.

EDIT 2: This question isn't a duplicate because the supposed duplicate linked is just an advice article of many different reasons why a cron job might be going wrong. My specific case might not be in that article. I have gone through most things in that article and I still cannot get it to work.

Comment: Please post plain text, not images.

Comment: @Barmar Editing it now.

Comment: You'll need to edit your question to show *why* it's not a dupe, not just assert that it isn't.

Comment: @womble I have done so and no response. I've already been through plenty of material/articles trying to fix this and I have gone through most things on that article also.

Comment: You need to use SSH keys for this. That's how you can authenticate without having to interact in order to input a password.